# How can I implement projectile motion like angry birds?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have to implement the projectile motion in my game as it was implemented in angry birds.
Please help ?

Comment: Consider asking our Game Development site ? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: i need to create action in which when user though object it should create the projectile of 15% .it may be from both sides randomly.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good example of this can be found in the opensource cocos 2D game Gorillas from Lhunath. You can find it https://github.com/Lyndir/Gorillas/tree/master/Gorillas.

Especially the ThrowController.m file will be of interest to you.

With this approach you just describe every point on the path of the object you are throwing (in this case bananas) with a simple formula.

after this it is simple math to define your trajectory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory

extra points if you also want to include external forces on the projectile.

Another possible way to go is to let a physics engine do the hard part, for cocos 2D you can use chipmunk and Box2d. I haven't tried one or the other, but if you are interested you should check out ray wenderlich's tutorial, usually they are great ;-).  : http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls